# TFS Remerge/Rebranch/Reintegrate

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

I have a scenario where I have the root project that has the code that is in production, and I two branches off of that.  One if for maintenance for when we have defect fixes, and minor enhancements.  The other branch name "Major" is for a major enhancement that will take us 4 months before we are ready to deploy.  When we make a change to the maintenance branch, we will want to merge that to root when we deploy, and then merge the changes into the Major branch as well.  I don't see how to do that in TFS.  In the past I thought I could just use branch from the root folder and choose Major as the target, but TFS complains that the branch already exists.  Suggestions?

```
root
 |
 |--Maintenance
 |--Major
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do what you are suggesting.  I'm curious about "... I thought I could just use branch from the root folder and choose Major..."  You would **merge**, not **branch**.

Your steps would be:

1. Merge from root to Maintenance (to ensure synchronicity)
2. Merge from Maintenance to root (for deployment)
3. Merge from root to Major (for forward integration)

If you cannot perform these steps, then perhaps the branches were not created from the root.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes, that was the key, merge not branch.

Answer (score 1):

You want to merge. You merge from `Maintenance` to `root`, then merge from `root` to `Major`.